# Windows forms spinning in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two windows forms.Now I have to close first one and show the second form and vice-versa.How can i do it.I was passing this pointer to the constructor of second form and then trying to 
close it,but this did not work.I can not  use showdialog here.

Comment: Could you add some sample code, please?

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677528/winform-forms-closing-and-opening-a-new-form

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing a form and then call another one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751076/closing-a-form-and-then-call-another-one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add static variables to each form in the Program class:

```
static class Program
{
    public static Form1 f1=null;
    public static Form2 f2 = null;

    public static FullClose=false;

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        f1=new Form1();
        f2 = new Form2();

        Application.Run(f1);
    }
}
```

Then in the Form_Closing event of each form:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (Program.FullClose==false)
    {
       e.Cancel = true;
       this.Visible = false;

       Program.f2.Show();
    }
}
```

(Change `Program.f2.Show()` to  `Program.f1.Show()` in Form2).

Of course this will stop the application from ever closing, so you should provide an extra button (or similar) that sets a boolean static variable (FullClose) that the Form_Closing events can check to see if they should properly close or not.

Answer (score 0):

You must set in your application, the close is not then main form was closed, then if all forms all closed.

You must pass the pointer of the main form to second form and main form must have second form pointer.

Then implement in your forms `OnClosing` event, then in her implementation open other form if this success return, else set Cancel to true and return.

Answer (score 0):

In every case there is one form, which represents the live of your application. This form will be started within your `Program.cs` file by calling

```
Application.Run(new MyForm());
```

If you try to start within this form another one and this will afterwards kill his creator, this will always lead to some bad designs.

Instead you should create some *super-form*. It is invisible and contains the glue code between those two forms. Right after startup it creates both forms and shows the first one. Also it registers to an (self-written) event in both forms which claims to show the other one. If your invisible form gets the event from one form it just makes the sender invisible and shows up the other one.

Last but not least you need in both (or at least in one) forms a second event, which will close the super form thous closing the application.