# Hide and show Form in WinForms application

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Winform Forms Closing and opening a new form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677528/winform-forms-closing-and-opening-a-new-form)

In my windows application I have two forms; form1 and form2

In form1 I listen to a button click with the following handler,

```
private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 updatewindow = new Form2();
    updatewindow.Show();
}
```

In Form2 I want to click on a button and show the first form, form1, so the button click handler in form2 does the following

```
private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
        {

            string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "codedata.xml");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(path);
            XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("Root/data[Sno='" + getsnofromform1 + "']");
            nodelist[0].ChildNodes[2].InnerText = txt_productcodeupdate.Text;
            nodelist[0].ChildNodes[3].InnerText = txt_productnameupdate.Text;
            nodelist[0].ChildNodes[4].InnerText = txt_brandcodeupdate.Text;
            nodelist[0].ChildNodes[5].InnerText = txt_brandnameupdate.Text;
            doc.Save(path);
            MessageBox.Show("Selected Record Updated Successfully");

        }
        catch
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            //txt_sno.Text = "";
            // txt_companycode.Text = "";
            txt_productcodeupdate.Text = "";
            txt_productnameupdate.Text = "";
            txt_brandcodeupdate.Text = "";
            txt_brandnameupdate.Text = "";

            BarcodeCount form1 = new BarcodeCount();
            form1.BringToFront();
            form1.Invalidate();
            Application.OpenForms["BarcodeCount"].Refresh();
            this.Close();
        }
}
```

The problem is I want to display the old form, but instead a new Form1 window is opening.

i want to refresh the form1 form form2

Comment: If you want only to close the form, why you instantiate a new form1 again?

Comment: when you do `= new Form1()` you are creating a *new Form1*. You are not referring to the already created one. Is that the issue you are having?

Comment: i want the form1 in deactive mode, and if i click the form2 button, then form2 will close and form1 should in active mode

Comment: @chitra I am still not understanding your problem. Are you trying to open the **old** Form1 or do you want to create a **new** one?

Comment: i want to again redirect to form1 and it should refresh form1

Comment: @chitra: I edited your question based on how I interpreted your actual problem to highlight it further. You are free to rollback if I misinterpreted.

Comment: All things apart, How does compiler allowed you to declare variable "for"!!!!

Comment: @SwanandPurankar: Not that the example in the OP:s question illustrates it, but you can slap a @ in front of for and that's a valid variable name. `int @for = 0`

Comment: is there any other options plz;

Answer (score 3):

```
FormName x = default(FormName);
x = new FormName();
x.Show();
x = null;
```

x being either Form1 or Form2 when needed.

Comment: OP's using C#, yet you post VB?

Comment: You usually shouldn't explicitly set a variable to Nothing. In almost all cases you should let the [garbage collector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2839/540352) do the cleanup for you.

Comment: @Laoujin I like to be effcient ;)

Comment: Since when is setting to null an efficient strategy? Never saw that in recommended practices... If that was the optimal approach, why on Earth would anyone invent GC, if all you needed to do was `=null`? Also, are you 100% sure it correctly disposes all the resources associated with the form? (sql connection etc.)

Comment: It just frees up the memory that is no longer required. Otherwise 'click, click, click...oh no memory left' Does the code above answer the question? Yes. OP can decide if he wants to include the last line.

Comment: @Ryan McDonough: Did you read the link in my previous comment? First, setting x to null will not actually free up memory. The form itself cannot be GC'd since it's currently visible to the user! The only thing that you could free up at this point is the x *reference* (ie 32/64 bits) but even that doesn't happen. Memory has been reserved for x, it doesn't matter if it is pointing to an instance or not. Second, setting `x = null` might actually result in that memory being in use *longer*. (For example when the GC kicks in between the `x.Show()` and `x = null` statements.)

Comment: @Laoujin fair enough, I'll keep that mind in future.

Comment: @walther: No it will not do such thing! Setting `x = null` doesn't really do anything. If the form holds onto unmanaged resources such as an SQLConnection, the cleanup for this should be done by implementing [IDisposable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/538238/540352) (or a more visual explaination [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4874/Another-Look-At-IDisposable).) Even more off topic, having a form hold onto a SQLConnection is in violation of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Comment: any idea for this, still its not working for me

Answer (score 0):

If you make the `_for` a class field, you can always open that one instance by calling `for.Show();`.

Example:

```
private Form1 _for = new Form1();
private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 for.Show();
}
```