# How to hide a form without resetting the loop

Tags: c#, winforms

In my program there are 2 forms. There is a loop function in Form1. I can show Form2 from a button. By using:

```
Form1 form2 = new Form2();
frm2.show();
```

method. When I pressed a button on From2 to show Form1, Form1 starts its loop again(resets). How can I hide Form1 temporary  and show it again from the point it hides.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide and show Form in WinForms application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213513/hide-and-show-form-in-winforms-application)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Winform Forms Closing and opening a new form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677528/winform-forms-closing-and-opening-a-new-form)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Form1.Hide()` which keeps the instance alive while don't displays it. For better answers you need to provide more code and also better explanation of your case scenario.